# ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "someUrl" Connection timed out

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'm trying to consume a external service response in my processor which is async(multithreaded) and writing to my database(Sybase) through async writer. I have been getting an I/O error

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://pcmiler.alk.com/apis/rest/v1.0/Service.svc/route/routeReports": Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemWriter.write(AsyncItemWriter.java:44) ~[spring-batch-integration-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.9.RELEASE]
```

which is followed by

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; 
SQL [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?, STATUS = ?, 
COMMIT_COUNT = ?, READ_COUNT = ?, FILTER_COUNT = ?, WRITE_COUNT = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, 
EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, READ_SKIP_COUNT = ?, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT = ?, 
WRITE_SKIP_COUNT = ?, ROLLBACK_COUNT = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ? 
and VERSION = ?]; Attempt to update or insert row failed because resultant row of size 
2633 bytes is larger than the maximum size (1962 bytes) allowed for this table.
; nested exception is com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: Attempt to update or 
insert row failed because resultant row of size 2633 bytes is larger than the maximum 
size (1962 bytes) allowed for this table.
```

Below is my configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;



@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;


@Bean
public JdbcPagingItemReader<DistanceFinderModel> reader() {
    JdbcPagingItemReader<DistanceFinderModel> reader = new 
 JdbcPagingItemReader<>();

    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setFetchSize(200);
    reader.setRowMapper(new DistanceFinderRowMapper());

    SybasePagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new 
 SybasePagingQueryProvider();
    queryProvider.setSelectClause("*");
    queryProvider.setFromClause("from distance_finder");
    queryProvider.setWhereClause("batch_id='102'");
    Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>(2);
    sortKeys.put("batch_id", Order.ASCENDING);
    sortKeys.put("pair_id", Order.ASCENDING);

    queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
    reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
    return reader;
}



public class DistanceFinderRowMapper implements 
 RowMapper<DistanceFinderModel>
{

      @Override
      public DistanceFinderModel mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws 
  SQLException 
      {
          DistanceFinderModel data = new DistanceFinderModel();
          data.setBatch_id(rs.getString("batch_id"));
          data.setOrigin_lat(rs.getDouble("origin_lat"));
          data.setOrigin_long(rs.getDouble("origin_long"));
          data.setDest_lat(rs.getDouble("dest_lat"));
          data.setDest_long(rs.getDouble("dest_long"));
          data.setDistance(rs.getDouble("distance"));
          data.setPair_id(rs.getInt("pair_id"));
          return data;
      }
      
}

@Bean
public Processor processor(){
    return new Processor();
}

@Bean
public DBWriter writer()
{
    return new DBWriter();
}


@Bean
public AsyncItemWriter<DistanceFinderModel> asyncItemWriter() throws 
 Exception
{
        AsyncItemWriter<DistanceFinderModel> asyncItemWriter = new 
 AsyncItemWriter<>();
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(writer());
        asyncItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return asyncItemWriter;  
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Bean
    public AsyncItemProcessor asyncItemProcessor() throws Exception
{
        AsyncItemProcessor<DistanceFinderModel, DistanceFinderModel> 
 asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor<>();
        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(processor());
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        asyncItemProcessor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return asyncItemProcessor;
    }

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
public Step step1() throws Exception{
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1"). 
<DistanceFinderModel,DistanceFinderModel>chunk(300)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(asyncProcessor())
            .writer(asyncItemWriter())
            //.taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job exportPerosnJob() throws Exception{
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("exportPeronJob").incrementer(new 
 RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1()).end().build();
}



 }
```

Below is my processor

```
@Component
public class Processor implements ItemProcessor<DistanceFinderModel, 
DistanceFinderModel> {

static int count =0;
public Processor() {
    
}

@Override
public DistanceFinderModel process(DistanceFinderModel val) throws Exception 
{
    
    System.out.println("Processsing..");
    Thread.sleep(200);
    System.out.println("Calculating distance");
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String requestURL = "someURl";
    Object data = restTemplate.getForObject(requestURL, Object.class);
    
    if(data==null)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not find distance for ");
        System.out.println(val.getPair_id());
        return null;
    }
    //Here I parse the distance from response.
    val.setDistance(parsedDistanceValue);
    
}
}
```

Below is my writer which updates the row in sybase

```
@Component
public class DBWriter implements ItemWriter<DistanceFinderModel> {

@Autowired
private DistanceFinderRepository distanceFinderRepository;
static int batch=1;
@Override
public void write(List<? extends DistanceFinderModel> data) throws Exception 
{

    System.out.println("Data Saved for batch: " + batch++);
    distanceFinderRepository.save(data);
}
}
```

I coudn't find any references in the internet for this error.I tried altering BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table as its row size was huge. After altering I only get the ResourceAccessException and the DataIntegrityException(follow up error which I posted above) seems to have gone. Can anyone throw some light here? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: There is an error. it tries to write the message into the `EXIT_MESSAGE` field. That fails probably due to some specific sybase settings for max row size/record size or whatever.

Comment: Your clue lies in ".. Attempt to update or insert row failed because resultant row of size 2633 bytes is larger than the maximum size (1962 bytes) allowed for this table ..". Apparently the db update is failing due to sybase server side limit on the maximum row size for this table. This db insertion failure is wrapped in ExecutionException (as expected) for async execution. Please verify table's row limit on sybase side. [This](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20021_1251/html/locking/locking70.htm) might help.

Comment: @M.Deinum I can see that the columns "EXIT_MESSAGE" and "EXIT_CODE" in BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION are of type varchar(2500) each. Can I alter this table? As it is auto generated by spring batch process. Because I can't change the sybase settings.

Comment: You can but I think things will fail especially the `EXIT_MESSAGE` the `EXIT_CODE` shouldn't be that large.

Comment: Do you mean to say that there was an error which already occured and BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION is trying to write that message in "EXIT_MESSAGE" and this is again creating another error?

Comment: @M.Deinum I reduced the size of "EXIT_MESSAGE" and "EXIT_CODE" now this error ".. Attempt to update or insert row failed because resultant row of size 2633 bytes is larger than the maximum size (1962 bytes) allowed for this table .." is gone. But the 1st error ExecutionException is only present. How do I get rid of this ? I have updated the post with the code. Please assist as I've been stuck with this from 1 week.Thanks:)

Comment: That is not what this question is about. You are getting a timeout (i.e. server takes too long to respond) and the batch jobs simply stops.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes. How can I avoid this connection time out?Please assist